# ¿Cómo recuperar la sentencia cuando ocurre un error en el SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un proceso que entre tantas cosas inserta registros de acuerdo a ciertas peticiones, como el número de transacciones es alto, tengo una tabla para guardar los errores *(cuando ocurren)* y si ocurre un error en ese `insert` envío a escribir todo el `SQL` en cuestión en un `archivo txt`.

Sin embargo me he topado con un registro que no sea insertado *(me he percatado porque que del lado de las peticiones si tengo el registro)*.

Quisiera saber si accediendo a algún tipo de logs propio de SQL Server puedo recuperar la sentencia SQL en donde ocurrió el error con el fin de realizar algún tipo de validación.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx

https://soportesql.wordpress.com/tag/log-de-errores-sql/

Comment: Sin duda el [Sqlprofiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181091.aspx)